# need some modrewrite regex syntax

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Trying to write a redirect that is a little out of the norm for me.  Wondering if someone could help me with the syntax.

Concept is this: 
Old URL: /$year/$month/$title/
New URL: /$title/

```
RewriteRule: <old domain>/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/  <new domain>/$3/? [R=301,L]
```

Thanks
Citti

Comment: Do you only need to capture the last section of the URL, or the 3rd section?

Comment: Sorry when i submitted my post it wripped out my example. I updated my orig post.

Comment: In this case, there shouldn't be any reason to perform all of these captures.  A simple regex such as `.+/(.+?)/?$` should do the trick, then just replace with `http://newdomain/$1/`

Comment: Hmm this seems to be redirecting images to the new URL which are actually two directories deeper... For some reason this has not effect on the actual posts themselves.

Comment: Ok I just needed to reorder the htaccess. The above works when placed at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `old domain` in `RewriteRule`. That can only match `REQUEST_URI`.

Use code like this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ http://newdomain.com/$3/? [R=301,L]
```